# Extending with filter queries with entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have 3 tables in my testdatabase, Customers <-> CustomersUsergroups <-> Usergroups

For customers I have a method that returns all Usergroups like this:

```
        public IQueryable<Usergroup> GetUsergroups()
    {
        return from ug in _entities.UsergroupSet.Include("Customer")
               select ug;
    }
```

And to that I have a "filter-class" for class Usergroup

```
        public static IQueryable<Usergroup> ByUsergroupID(this IQueryable<Usergroup> qry, int usergroupID)
    {
        return from ug in qry
               where ug.UsergroupID == usergroupID
               select ug;
    }
```

so when I type:

```
return _repository.GetUsergroups().ByUsergroupID(usergroupID);
```

it works great, but the problem now is that I would like to extend so I can filter by CustomerID aswell, sort of like:

```
public static IQueryable<Customer> ByCustomerID(this IQueryable<Customer> qry, int customerID)
    {
        return from c in qry
               where c.CustomerID == customerID
               select c;
    }
```

so I can use it like:

```
return _repository.GetUsergroups().ByCustomerID(customerID);
```

is that possible to do with just using "Include"? or isnt it an easy way to fix that since they are different classes?

Thanks in advance

/M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand problem the way you described, but it is normal that you can't use method ByCustomerID because you defined extension on `IQueryable<Customer>` not on `IQueryable<UserGroup>`.

If you want to define it on `IQueryable<UserGroup>` and **if you intended to get UserGroups assigned to one Customer** that can be done like this:

```
public static IQueryable<UserGroup> ByCustomerID(this IQueryable<UserGroup> qry, int customerID)
     {
         return from ug in qry
                from c in ug.Customer
                where c.CustomerID == customerID
                select ug;
     }
```